# Ionic Error: An error occurred while running subprocess cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I am trying to run the ionic app for android but it gives me below error.

[image]

**Build is successful but an error occurred while running subprocess cordova.**

If i run the ionic app for browser, then it's okay. No error happens.

**config.xml:**

```
<engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
```

**package.json:**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.7.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4"
}
```

I tried removing the platform folder and adding it again but the same error came.

Can anyone point me out the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the device was not connected and i was trying to run for android. When i connected one android device, it ran fine. Silly mistake though.